# Installing development libraries on 14.04

Tags: apt, application-development

I am trying to build some application for both amd64 and i386 architectures.
Host architecture is amd64. So i compile and link with -m32. Compilation is done ok but linker cannot find libraries. Installing of i386 development libraries (for example apt-get install libfltk-dev:i386) deletes related amd64 libraries and vice versa.
So the question is how to install/keep development libraries for both architectures?

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need libfltk-dev. Because dev packages contain headers, and headers are the same for all architectures (this is probably a reason why they conflict).

To make the linker happy, something like libfltk1.3:i386 or libfltk1.1:i386 is needed. Packages of this kind contain shared libraries.

Comment: Sometimes headers can be different for different architectures. And both libfltk1.3:i386  and libfltk1.3:amd64 are installed.

Comment: Then add some -L linker flags.

Comment: Adding libraries paths for cross compiling while not adding them for host compiling does not look like the "true way". Any more ideas?